# How to use a compare function for a specific field within a struct?

Tags: c, struct, compare

Let's say that I have the following struct:

```
struct Person
{
   int age;
   int weight;
   int height;
};
```

I want to use a "generic" compare function which will take two instances of struct person and then compare them by comparing two specific fields.

Let's say that my compare function will be look like this:

```
int compare(void *first_data, void *second_data, void *param)
{
    if (first_data->param > second_data->param)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (first_data->param < second_data->param)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas `void *first_data` will represent the the first instance of struct Person, `void *second_Data` will represent the second instance of struct Person and `void *param` somehow will instruct the function according to which field the structs will be compared.
Currently I have no idea how to use this "void *param" for this purpose.
For example-how can I compare these two instances by the "weight" field?

Comment: `void *first_data` Why is it `void *` and not `const struct Person *`? `void *param` Does it _have to_ be `void *` type? Can it be other type? Why is everything `void *`? Is `struct Person` always going to have only `int` members, or do you want to handle other types?

Comment: Can you work `param` as a `int`? `if (param == 0) return first_data->age - second_data->age;`

Comment: You could write it as a macro .

Comment: You need to cast the void * before dereferencing it, and param is a variable but you use it as a member name.  You cannot, at run-time, map a name of a member to it's member as that information is simply not available. You can write code that does this, say, making param and enum then in code handle every value.  Or a function per member.  A better option is probably to generate that via a macro, but again it has to be done at compile time.  `#define compare(a, b, f) if(((struct Person *) a)->(f) > ((struct Person *) b)->(f)) return -1; ... `.

Comment: It sould be *first_data and not const struct Person * because the compare function should be as much generic as possible (This function actually will be used for binary search tree insertion, whereas the data of a single node can be a struct or just an int/char/etc).
I have mention a struct with ints only, but it can contain a mixture of ints, chars, float and etc.
Macro maybe will work, but I have an api which restricts me to use the mentioned compare signature, I am just trying to figure out how can it be possible to use this additional void *param argument.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `param`, pass in the offset of the desired member.  Since all members are `int`, a common compare is possible.

```
#include <stddef.h>

int Person_compare(const struct Person *first_data, 
    const struct Person *second_data, size_t param_offset) {
  int first  = *(int *)((char *)first_data + param_offset);
  int second = *(int *)((char *)second_data + param_offset);
  return (first < second) - (first > second);
}
```

Example use:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int weight_cmp = Person_compare(&pa, &pb, offsetof(struct Person, weight));
```

---

If the members' types differ, use of `_Generic` to steer compare function selection is possible.